# how to make looping and appending more efficient

Tags: r, for-loop

I have this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

datalist = list()
files <- list.files("/WEIGHTS1/Retina", pattern=".RDat", ignore.case=T)

for(i in files)
{
a<-get(load(i))
names <- rownames(a)
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(names,a))
rownames(data) <- NULL
dd=na.omit(concat.split.multiple(data = data, split.cols = c("names"), seps = ":"))
dd=select(dd,names_1,blup,names_3,names_4)
colnames(dd)=c("rsid","weight","ref_allele","eff_allele")
dd$WGT<-i
datalist[[i]] <- dd # add it to your list
}

big_data = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

There is 17345 RDat files this loop has to go through. And each file has approximately 10,000 lines. All RDat files can be downloaded from [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE115828)
and they are compressed in this file: GSE115828_retina_TWAS_wgts.tar.gz . And subset of 3 of those .RDat files is [here](https://github.com/montenegrina/sample)

for i="retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat"

```
> head(dd)
          rsid        weight ref_allele eff_allele
1:  rs72763981  9.376766e-09          C          G
2: rs144383755 -2.093346e-09          A          G
3:   rs1925717  1.511376e-08          T          C
4:  rs61827307 -1.625302e-08          C          A
5:  rs61827308 -1.625302e-08          G          C
6: rs199623136 -9.128354e-10         GC          G
                           WGT
1: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
2: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
3: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
4: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
5: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
6: retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat
```

and

```
> head(data)
                      names               top1          blup lasso enet
1  rs72763981:228705421:C:G  0.972975476445267  9.376766e-09     0    0
2 rs144383755:228705758:A:G -0.274895726835564 -2.093346e-09     0    0
3                 rs1925716 -0.739883956565433 -1.993259e-08     0    0
4   rs1925717:228707734:T:C  0.725883147262975  1.511376e-08     0    0
5  rs61827307:228708434:C:A -0.783489562399769 -1.625302e-08     0    0
6  rs61827308:228708526:G:C -0.783489562399769 -1.625302e-08     0    0
```

If I load just one .RDat file:

```
i="retina.ENSG00000135776.wgt.RDat"

a<-get(load(i))

> head(a)
                            top1          blup lasso enet
rs72763981:228705421:C:G   0.9729755  9.376766e-09     0    0
rs144383755:228705758:A:G -0.2748957 -2.093346e-09     0    0
rs1925716                 -0.7398840 -1.993259e-08     0    0
rs1925717:228707734:T:C    0.7258831  1.511376e-08     0    0
rs61827307:228708434:C:A  -0.7834896 -1.625302e-08     0    0
rs61827308:228708526:G:C  -0.7834896 -1.625302e-08     0    0
```

One can see that fro "names" column I am creating 3 separate columns: "rsid","ref_allele", and "eff_allele".
This loop takes a very long time to execute. Is there is a way to make this faster?

I am trying @akrun code bellow:

```
library(parallel)
library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

n <-  parallel::detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n, type = "SOCK")   
doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
files <- list.files("/WEIGHTS1/Retina", pattern=".RDat", ignore.case=T)

lst_out <- foreach::foreach(i = seq_along(files), 
              .packages = c("data.table") ) %dopar% {

   a <- get(load(files[i]))
   names <- rownames(a)
   if("blup" %in% colnames(a)) {
     data <- data.table(names, a["blup"])
     nm1 <- c("rsid", "ref_allele", "eff_allele")
     data[,  (nm1) := tstrsplit(names, ":")[-2]]
     out <- data[, .(rsid, weight = blup, ref_allele, eff_allele)][,
               WGT := files[i]][]
    } else {
  
     data <- data.table(names)
     nm1 <- c("rsid", "ref_allele", "eff_allele")
     data[,  (nm1) := tstrsplit(names, ":")[-2]]
     out <- data[, .(rsid,  ref_allele, eff_allele)][,
               WGT := files[i]][]
       }

   return(out)
   rm(data, a)
   gc()
 }

Error in { : task 12 failed - "object 'blup' not found"


big_data <- rbindlist(lst_out)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226010/discussion-on-question-by-anamaria-how-to-make-looping-and-appending-more-effici).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to make this more faster.  1) An option is to use `tstrsplit` from `data.table`, 2) Do this using `parallel`

```
library(parallel)
library(data.table)
n <-  parallel::detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n, type = "SOCK")   
doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)
files <- list.files("/WEIGHTS1/Retina", pattern=".RDat", ignore.case=TRUE)

lst_out <- foreach::foreach(i = seq_along(files), 
                  .packages = c("data.table") ) %dopar% {

   tmp <-  as.data.frame(get(load(files[i])))
   a <- data.table::copy(tmp)
   rm(tmp)
   gc()
   
   names <- rownames(a)
   if("blup" %in% colnames(a)) {
     data <- data.table(names, a["blup"])
     nm1 <- c("rsid", "ref_allele", "eff_allele")
     data[,  (nm1) := tstrsplit(names, ":")[-2]]
     out <- data[, .(rsid, weight = blup, ref_allele, eff_allele)][,
               WGT := files[i]][]
    } else {
      
     data <- data.table(names)
     nm1 <- c("rsid", "ref_allele", "eff_allele")
     data[,  (nm1) := tstrsplit(names, ":")[-2]]
     out <- data[, .(rsid,  ref_allele, eff_allele)][,
               WGT := files[i]][]
   }

   return(out)
   rm(data)
   gc()
 }
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

big_data <- rbindlist(lst_out, fill = TRUE)
```

-testing

```
a1 <- structure(list(top1 = c(0.9729755, -0.2748957, -0.739884, 0.7258831, 
-0.7834896, -0.7834896), blup = c(9.376766e-09, -2.093346e-09, 
-1.993259e-08, 1.511376e-08, -1.625302e-08, -1.625302e-08), lasso = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), enet = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("rs72763981:228705421:C:G", 
"rs144383755:228705758:A:G", "rs1925716", "rs1925717:228707734:T:C", 
"rs61827307:228708434:C:A", "rs61827308:228708526:G:C"))


lst1 <- replicate(16, a1, simplify = FALSE)
file_nm <- sprintf("retina.ENSG00000%d.wgt.RDat", 135776:135791)

library(foreach)
library(parallel)
library(data.table)
n <-  parallel::detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(n, type = "SOCK")   
doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)


lst_out <- foreach::foreach(i = seq_along(lst1), 
                  .packages = c("data.table") ) %dopar% {

   a <- lst1[[i]]
   names <- rownames(a)
   data <- data.table(names, a["blup"])
   nm1 <- c("rsid", "ref_allele", "eff_allele")
   data[,  (nm1) := tstrsplit(names, ":")[-2]]
   return(data[, .(rsid, weight = blup, ref_allele, eff_allele)][,
               WGT := file_nm[i]][])
 }
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

big_data <- rbindlist(lst_out) 

dim(big_data)
#[1] 96  5
```

Comment: your code only needs a=as.data.frame(a) after a <- data.table::copy(tmp) and it works as expected and also fast.

Comment: I will just add that one line. And thank you very much!